# Macro or VBA script to effectively split an empty cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am aware that in Excel you cannot split a cell. However, a way around that would be to insert a new row beneath, and merge vertically all of the neighbors on the left and right (for very many cells)

I want a keyboard shortcut to do this. So I recorded a macro to do this, but the problem is the macro doesn't take into account what position my cursor is in, and always goes to the same spot, which is not what I want. I want to press the keys and the split happens right at the highlighted cell.

[image]

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
    Range("A2:A3").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Range("C2:C3").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:FP3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C2:FP3").Select
    Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If you included the actual script we could point out exactly where you need to replace `Range("B2")` with `ActiveCell` ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon ah good call. I'd never done this before lol. I am currently working through and trying to generalize the ranges to the active cell.

Comment: Simply write me,,, Are you trying to split BLANK CELLS in between some Filled CELLS ?

Comment: **If you mean splitting a column in a table into more sub columns - like you one can do with in  MS Word, then, NO, you can't do this in Excel.** However, you CAN split the contents of Column into new columns by specifying a comma  as the  delirmeter to split the data.